# Busca do cursor: o número de variáveis declaradas na lista INTO deve corresponder ao número de colunas selecionadas

Tags: sql, sql-server, tsql

Olá!

Fiz um T-SQL e no momento executar está dando a mensagem:

> Mensagem 16924, Nível 16, Estado 1, Linha 58
> Busca do cursor: o número de variáveis declaradas na lista INTO deve corresponder ao número de colunas selecionadas.

Alguém sabe me posicionar o que está errado?

```
'''
    Declare @Seq INT, @ConfigAntiga INT, @ConfigNova INT,
    @Indicador Nvarchar(60),@ContabilCred int,@ContabilDeb int,@ContabilPessoa int,@rateio int,
    @ContabilHistorico nvarchar(1000),@FinancCred int,
    @FinancDeb int,@FinancHistorico nvarchar(1000),@CResultado int,
    @Formula nvarchar(500),@Acrescimo char(1),@Desconto char(1),
    @Visualizar char(1),@Ordem INT,
    @OperacaoAntiga INT, @Operacao INT
    
    SELECT @OperacaoAntiga = 36 --COLOCAR O SEQUENCIAL DA OPERAÇAO NA EMPRESA ANTIGA.
         , @Operacao = 498 --COLOCAR O SEQUENCIAL DA OPERAÇAO NA EMPRESA NOVA.
    
    
    DECLARE ConfigTributos CURSOR FOR
        
        Select Sequencial From ConfigTributos where Operacao = @OperacaoAntiga
        
    OPEN ConfigTributos 
        FETCH NEXT FROM ConfigTributos INTO @ConfigAntiga
        WHILE @@Fetch_Status <> -1 BEGIN        
        
            INSERT INTO ConfigTributos (Operacao,RegimeOrigem,RegimeDestino,TipoRecurso,Recurso,STICMS,BASEICMS,AliICMS,Substituicao,IsentosOutros,
            ContaDebFinICMS,ContaCredFinICMS,HistoricoFinICMS,ContaDebContabICMS,ContaCredContabICMS,HistoricoContabICMS,ApuraICMS,
            EnquadramentoIPI,STIPI,BaseIPI,AliqIPI,IncideIPI,ContaDebFinIPI,ContaCredFinIPI,HistoricoFinIPI,ContaDebContabIPI,
            ContaCredContabIPI,HistoricoContabIPI,ApuraIPI,STPIS,BasePIS,AliqPIS,IncidePIS,ContaDebFinPIS,ContaCredFinPIS,
            HistoricoFinPIS,ContaDebContabPIS,ContaCredContabPIS,HistoricoContabPIS,ApuraPIS,STCOFINS,BaseCOFINS,AliqCOFINS,
            IncideCOFINS,ContaDebFinCofins,ContaCredFinCofins,HistoricoFinCofins,ContaDebContabCofins,ContaCredContabCofins,
            HistoricoContabCofins,ApuraCofins,STPISS,BaseISS,AliqISS,IncideISS,ContaDebFinISS,ContaCredFinISS,HistoricoFinISS,
            ContaDebContabISS,ContaCredContabISS,HistoricoContabISS,ApuraISS,CRFinICMS,CRContabICMS,CRFinIPI,CRContabIPI,CRFinPIS,
            CRContabPIS,CRFinConfins,CRContabConfins,CRFinISS,CRContabISS,CFOPDentroEst,CFOPForaEst,CFOPImportExport,EstadoOrigemICMS,
            EstadoDestinoICMS,ListaServico,ContabICMS,ContabIPI,ContabPIS,ContabCOFINS,ContabISSQN,AliqSubstIcms,DeduzirICMS,DeduzirIPI,
            DeduzirPIS,DeduzirCOFINS,DeduzirISSQN,MVA,DiferencaICMS,BaseSubICMS,NatBcCredPis,NatBcCredCofins,NatCredPis,NatCredCofins,Descricao, UnidadeNegocio)
            
            Select @Operacao,RegimeOrigem,RegimeDestino,TipoRecurso,Recurso,STICMS,BASEICMS,AliICMS,Substituicao,IsentosOutros,
            ContaDebFinICMS,ContaCredFinICMS,HistoricoFinICMS,ContaDebContabICMS,ContaCredContabICMS,HistoricoContabICMS,ApuraICMS,
            EnquadramentoIPI,STIPI,BaseIPI,AliqIPI,IncideIPI,ContaDebFinIPI,ContaCredFinIPI,HistoricoFinIPI,ContaDebContabIPI,
            ContaCredContabIPI,HistoricoContabIPI,ApuraIPI,STPIS,BasePIS,AliqPIS,IncidePIS,ContaDebFinPIS,ContaCredFinPIS,
            HistoricoFinPIS,ContaDebContabPIS,ContaCredContabPIS,HistoricoContabPIS,ApuraPIS,STCOFINS,BaseCOFINS,AliqCOFINS,
            IncideCOFINS,ContaDebFinCofins,ContaCredFinCofins,HistoricoFinCofins,ContaDebContabCofins,ContaCredContabCofins,
            HistoricoContabCofins,ApuraCofins,STPISS,BaseISS,AliqISS,IncideISS,ContaDebFinISS,ContaCredFinISS,HistoricoFinISS,
            ContaDebContabISS,ContaCredContabISS,HistoricoContabISS,ApuraISS,CRFinICMS,CRContabICMS,CRFinIPI,CRContabIPI,CRFinPIS,
            CRContabPIS,CRFinConfins,CRContabConfins,CRFinISS,CRContabISS,CFOPDentroEst,CFOPForaEst,CFOPImportExport,EstadoOrigemICMS,
            EstadoDestinoICMS,ListaServico,ContabICMS,ContabIPI,ContabPIS,ContabCOFINS,ContabISSQN,AliqSubstIcms,DeduzirICMS,DeduzirIPI,
            DeduzirPIS,DeduzirCOFINS,DeduzirISSQN,MVA,DiferencaICMS,BaseSubICMS,NatBcCredPis,NatBcCredCofins,NatCredPis,NatCredCofins, Descricao, UnidadeNegocio
            FROM ConfigTributos where Sequencial = @ConfigAntiga    

            SELECT @ConfigNova = SEQUENCIAL From ConfigTributos where operacao = @Operacao 
            and RegimeOrigem =  ( SELECT RegimeOrigem From ConfigTributos where Sequencial = @ConfigAntiga)
            and RegimeDestino = ( SELECT RegimeDestino From ConfigTributos where Sequencial = @ConfigAntiga)
            and TipoRecurso =   ( SELECT TipoRecurso From ConfigTributos where Sequencial = @ConfigAntiga)
            and Recurso =       ( SELECT Recurso From ConfigTributos where Sequencial = @ConfigAntiga)        
          
            DECLARE AtualizaItens CURSOR FOR
            Select Indicador,ContabilCred,ContabilDeb,ContabilPessoa,ContabilHistorico,FinancCred,
            FinancDeb,FinancHistorico,CResultado,Formula,Acrescimo,Desconto,Visualizar,Ordem,@rateio,@rateio
            From IndicTributos Where SeqConfigTributos = @ConfigAntiga
            
            OPEN AtualizaItens 
                FETCH NEXT FROM AtualizaItens INTO  @Indicador ,@ContabilCred ,@ContabilDeb ,@ContabilPessoa ,
            @ContabilHistorico ,@FinancCred , @FinancDeb ,@FinancHistorico ,@CResultado ,
            @Formula ,@Acrescimo ,@Desconto , @Visualizar ,@Ordem ,@rateio
                WHILE @@Fetch_Status <> -1 BEGIN
                    
                    Select @Seq = Max(IsNull(Sequencial,0))+1 From IndicTributos
                    
                    Insert Into IndicTributos (Sequencial,Indicador,ContabilCred,ContabilDeb,ContabilPessoa,ContabilHistorico,FinancCred,
                    FinancDeb,FinancHistorico,CResultado,Formula,Acrescimo,Desconto,SeqConfigTributos,Visualizar,Ordem,Rateio)
                    
                    Select @Seq, @Indicador ,@ContabilCred ,@ContabilDeb ,@ContabilPessoa , @ContabilHistorico ,@FinancCred,
                    @FinancDeb ,@FinancHistorico ,@CResultado , @Formula ,@Acrescimo ,@Desconto, @ConfigNova , @Visualizar ,@Ordem,@rateio
                    
                FETCH NEXT FROM AtualizaItens INTO @Indicador ,@ContabilCred ,@ContabilDeb ,@ContabilPessoa ,
            @ContabilHistorico ,@FinancCred , @FinancDeb ,@FinancHistorico ,@CResultado ,
            @Formula ,@Acrescimo ,@Desconto , @Visualizar ,@Ordem ,@rateio
                END
            CLOSE AtualizaItens 
            DEALLOCATE AtualizaItens 
            
        FETCH NEXT FROM ConfigTributos INTO @ConfigAntiga
        END
    CLOSE ConfigTributos 
    DEALLOCATE ConfigTributos
```

Comment: Creio que a mensagem é clara. aqui: `DECLARE AtualizaItens CURSOR FOR Select Indicador,ContabilCred,ContabilDeb,ContabilPessoa,ContabilHistorico,FinancCred, FinancDeb,FinancHistorico,CResultado,Formula,Acrescimo,Desconto,Visualizar,Ordem,@rateio,@rateio
From IndicTributos Where SeqConfigTributos = @ConfigAntiga` você tem 16 campos e ...

Comment: ... aqui: `OPEN AtualizaItens  FETCH NEXT FROM AtualizaItens INTO  @Indicador ,@ContabilCred ,@ContabilDeb ,@ContabilPessoa ,@ContabilHistorico ,@FinancCred , @FinancDeb ,@FinancHistorico ,@CResultado , @Formula ,@Acrescimo ,@Desconto , @Visualizar ,@Ordem ,@rateio` tem 15 campos.

Comment: Caso a resposta tenha sido útil, não se esqueça de aceitá-la.

Answer (score 1):

Além de estar repetido, `@rateio` deveria ser simplesmente `rateio` nesta parte

```
DECLARE AtualizaItens CURSOR FOR
            Select Indicador,ContabilCred,ContabilDeb,ContabilPessoa,ContabilHistorico,FinancCred,
            FinancDeb,FinancHistorico,CResultado,Formula,Acrescimo,Desconto,Visualizar,Ordem,@rateio,@rateio
```

Comment: Ajudou demais. Muito obrigado!